# How double-wishbone front suspension in bike work?

Tags: mechanical-engineering

Some touring bikes like the BMW k 1600 have a really complicated front-end suspension mechanic.
I want to understand how the double-wishbone front suspension design differs from other fork suspensions.

[image: double-wishbone front suspension k1600]

Comment: It looks fairly standard double-wishbone to me but with the addition of the steering linkage sticking out the front. Can you [edit] your question to explain what exactly your difficulty is? It might save someone writing a load of stuff that you already know.

Answer (score 1):

These suspensions are designed to take out braking dive.  The linkages are complex but all make sense if you can spend enough time looking at them.

When a bike with typical forks brakes, the braking forces compress the spring/shock assembly ("dive").  These linkages avoid that and so the bike doesn't dive under braking.  Because of the extra weight & complexity, you will typically only find these on expensive touring bikes.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.
Can I have a more elaborate explanation about how the linkage prevents braking dive?
Since either fork or double-wishbone front suspension can be compressed in a verticle movement. So my imagination is that when the bike brake double-wishbone front suspension also got compressed.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cfrvd5FyWSs&ab_channel=RevvingHeart